# Combinando o valor de colunas com MySQL

Tags: mysql, bitwise

Estou trabalhando em um relatório em MySQL onde preciso mostrar um percentual de diversos eventos que ocorreram com um grupo de entidades.

A estrutura da minha tabela é a seguinte:

```
| id | eventoA | eventoB | eventoC | eventoD |
|----|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| 1  | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       |
| 2  | 1       | 0       | 0       | 0       |
| 3  | 1       | 0       | 0       | 0       |
| 4  | 0       | 0       | 1       | 0       |
| 5  | 0       | 1       | 0       | 0       |
| 6  | 1       | 1       | 0       | 0       |
| 7  | 1       | 1       | 0       | 0       |
| 8  | 1       | 0       | 1       | 0       |
| 9  | 0       | 0       | 1       | 0       |
| 10 | 0       | 0       | 0       | 0       |
```

As colunas `EventoA`, `EventoB` e assim por diante são do tipo `BIT` e são atualizadas pela aplicação quando determinado evento é disparado para aquela entidade. Hoje consigo gerar esse relatório com a seguinte *query*:

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `Total`,
  SUM(`eventoA`) AS `eventoDisparado`,
  COUNT(`id`) - SUM(`eventoA`) AS `eventoNaoDisparado`
FROM tabela;
```

Resultado da query:

> Total: 10 , eventoDisparado: 5, eventoNaoDisparado: 5

Porém dessa forma não consigo combinar múltiplos eventos pois o número de eventos acaba não batendo:

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS `Total`,
  SUM(`eventoA`) + SUM(`eventoB`) AS `eventoDisparado`,
  COUNT(`id`) - SUM(`eventoA`) + SUM(`eventoB`) AS `eventoNaoDisparado`
FROM tabela;
```

Resultado esperado:

> Total: 10 , eventoDisparado: 6, eventoNaoDisparado: 4

Resultado obtido

> Total: 10 , eventoDisparado: 8, eventoNaoDisparado: 2

Gostaria de certa forma combinar as colunas `eventoA` e `eventoB` dessa forma:

```
| id | eventoA | eventoB | eventoA + eventoB |
|----|---------|---------|-------------------|
| 1  | 0       | 0       | 0                 |
| 2  | 1       | 0       | 1                 |
| 3  | 1       | 0       | 1                 |
| 4  | 0       | 0       | 0                 |
| 5  | 0       | 1       | 1                 |
| 6  | 1       | 1       | 1                 |
| 7  | 1       | 1       | 1                 |
| 8  | 1       | 0       | 1                 |
| 9  | 0       | 0       | 0                 |
| 10 | 0       | 0       | 0                 |
```

Talvez consiga o resultado esperado utilizando um `OR` *bitwise*.

É possível utilizar esse tipo de operadores diretamente numa *query*? Quais outras alternativas eu tenho para conseguir o resultado esperado?

Comment: Não sei se entendi o que você precisa mas no mínima dá para fazer uma função que facilite o que deseja.

Comment: Baseado na tabela que você exibiu, qual é o resultado esperado? Teria como atualizar a pergunta com essa informação? Se possível em estrutura tabular, como você mostrou a tabela acima.

Comment: @cantoni ficou mais claro ?

Comment: Sim, ficou mais claro @gmsantos, obrigado. Uma dúvida, quantos campos de eventos são?

Comment: @gmsantos, no SQL Server funcionou a operação bit a bit, precisamos ver agora no MySQL. Vou dar uma checada aqui.

Comment: São 7 tipos de eventos

Comment: Ok, vou postar uma resposta aqui e veja se ela te atende.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiquei curioso, tentei usar operadores Binários e deu certo.

```
select count(entidade) as Total,
SUM(evento_a | evento_b) as EventoDisparado
from evento;
```

> Retorno: Total: 10, EventoDisparado: 6

Referência: [Documentação do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-or)

Comment: Isso mesmo que estava procurando

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um teste no SQL Server (para o MySQL ver o final da resposta) com duas versões, uma com os campos do tipo **int** e outra com o tipo **bit**. A versão do tipo **int** funcionou normalmente. Vou deixá-la aqui enquanto verifico a versão do tipo **bit**

**Versão com os campos do tipo int:**

```
create table teste (
  id int,
  eventoA int,
  eventoB int,
  eventoC int
);

insert into teste (id,eventoA,eventoB,eventoC) values (1,0,0,0);
insert into teste (id,eventoA,eventoB,eventoC) values (2,1,0,1);
insert into teste (id,eventoA,eventoB,eventoC) values (3,1,0,1);
insert into teste (id,eventoA,eventoB,eventoC) values (4,0,0,0);
insert into teste (id,eventoA,eventoB,eventoC) values (5,0,1,1);
insert into teste (id,eventoA,eventoB,eventoC) values (6,1,1,1);
insert into teste (id,eventoA,eventoB,eventoC) values (7,1,1,1);
insert into teste (id,eventoA,eventoB,eventoC) values (8,1,0,1);
insert into teste (id,eventoA,eventoB,eventoC) values (9,0,0,0);
insert into teste (id,eventoA,eventoB,eventoC) values (10,0,0,0);

SELECT 
  COUNT(*) TOTAL,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EVENTO = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) EVENTO_NAO_DISPARADO,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EVENTO = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) EVENTO_DISPARADO
FROM  
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        CASE WHEN SUM(eventoA + eventoB + eventoC) >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END EVENTO
    FROM TESTE
    GROUP BY ID
) A
```

**ATUALIZAÇÃO - Versão com o tipo bit:**

```
create table teste (
  id int,
  eventoA bit,
  eventoB bit,
  eventoC bit
)

insert into teste (id,eventoA,eventoB,eventoC) values (1,0,0,0)
insert into teste (id,eventoA,eventoB,eventoC) values (2,1,0,1)
insert into teste (id,eventoA,eventoB,eventoC) values (3,1,0,1)
insert into teste (id,eventoA,eventoB,eventoC) values (4,0,0,0)
insert into teste (id,eventoA,eventoB,eventoC) values (5,0,1,1)
insert into teste (id,eventoA,eventoB,eventoC) values (6,1,1,1)
insert into teste (id,eventoA,eventoB,eventoC) values (7,1,1,1)
insert into teste (id,eventoA,eventoB,eventoC) values (8,1,0,1)
insert into teste (id,eventoA,eventoB,eventoC) values (9,0,0,0)
insert into teste (id,eventoA,eventoB,eventoC) values (10,0,0,0)

SELECT 
  COUNT(*) TOTAL,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EVENTO = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) EVENTO_NAO_DISPARADO,
  SUM(CASE WHEN EVENTO = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) EVENTO_DISPARADO
FROM  
(
    SELECT
        ID,
        eventoA | eventoB | eventoC EVENTO
    FROM TESTE
) A
```

**ATUALIZAÇAO 2** - Fiddle MySQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20011/1/0

Nota: Não houve mudança para a versão com o tipo **bit** do SQL Server. A única coisa necessária foi incluir ";" ao final do Create Table e de cada Insert.

Comment: estou utilizando MySQL, poderia montar uma resposta para ele?

Comment: Vou utilizar o fiddle. Daqui a pouco chega aqui.